# How can I get data argument from serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I'm using Django and django-restframework.

I don't know How to access Serializer's argument.

I can access full json data from `serializer.data`. But when I tried to get argument like `id`, then it return error. `serializer.data.id`.

How can i get it? I used lots of time for search this, but failed.

I do this because update model based on user input.

e.g.

1. user input `id`.
2. get data with that `id`.
3. save that data to database.

I'm very very thanks for reading this.

## views.py

```python
class CareerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Career.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CareerSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsCreateable,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(nickname='test')
        print(serializer.data)
        print(serializer.data.id)
```

## Error

```
{'id': 14, 'created': '2017-04-26T12:39:58.249038Z', 'modified': '2017-04-26T12:39:58.249538Z', 'battle_tag': 'Fortune-1130', 'nickname': 'test', 'quick_eliminations': None, 'quick_damage_done': None, 'quick_deaths': None, 'quick_final_blows': None, 'quick_healing_done': None, 'quick_objective_kills': None, 'quick_objective_time': None, 'quick_solo_kills': None, 'competitive_eliminations': None, 'competitive_damage_done': None, 'competitive_deaths': None, 'competitive_final_blows': None, 'competitive_healing_done': None, 'competitive_objective_kills': None, 'competitive_objective_time': None, 'competitive_solo_kills': None, 'games_won': None, 'competitive_rank': None, 'level': None}
Internal Server Error: /career/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Development\Venv\20170420\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "E:\Development\Venv\20170420\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "E:\Development\Venv\20170420\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "E:\Development\Venv\20170420\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Development\Venv\20170420\myvenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 83, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Development\Venv\20170420\myvenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 483, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "E:\Development\Venv\20170420\myvenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 443, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "E:\Development\Venv\20170420\myvenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Development\Venv\20170420\myvenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 21, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "E:\Development\Venv\20170420\overmatch_django\overwatch\views.py", line 38, in perform_create
    print(serializer.data.id)
AttributeError: 'ReturnDict' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`serializer.data` is a dictionary subclass (i.e. `ReturnDict`), access it as you would a vanilla dictionary:

```
id  = serializer.data['id']
```

Comment: I would recommend `id = serializer.data.get('id', None)` just in case.

Comment: @MateuszKnapczyk what's the difference?

Comment: @FarzadSoltani brackets is raising exception if there is no 'id', while 'get' never raise any exception. I don't see it as better than the other, it depends if we want exceptions or not.

Answer (score 1):

Use serializer.data.get('id'). serializer.data.id doest not work since its not a class object, rather a json/dict.